# mySQL query error SELECT?

Tags: mysql

I got this error when I'm trying a script.

```
mySQL query error: SELECT * FROM ibf_store_shopstock WHERE is_hidden='0' AND category=1 ORDER BY item_name ASC  LIMIT 0,

mySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
mySQL error code: 
Date: Monday 23rd 2012f July 2012 05:37:44 PM`
```

This is odd, since the very same script I tried on my localhost (MySQL 5.5.14) works just fine, but when I try it on live server (MySQL 5.1.63), it results in this error. I thought there's no big difference between the MySQL version?

Anyway here is a part of the suspected script (it's quite long):
http://pastebin.com/YaQwVPqT

Comment: So your query ends with comma?

Comment: @zerkms: I'm not sure, it's from the PHP script. It's in here: http://pastebin.com/YaQwVPqT

Comment: well - it's your job, so make some research and show us the **exact** query that fails

Comment: Ah yes indeed, I've found the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing  something after LIMIT clause `"LIMIT start_record", "offset"`

try

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ibf_store_shopstock 
WHERE is_hidden='0' AND 
      category=1 
ORDER BY item_name ASC  
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: Hmm... so what should I edit in the PHP script? If you don't mind to check it out here: http://pastebin.com/YaQwVPqT

Comment: Wait, nevermind. I've found it. I indeed missed that something after the LIMIT clause. Thanks a lot!